# Is monotonic and convergent series bounded by the limit?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Problem: Suppose that $X_1\leq X_2\leq\cdots $ and $X_n \stackrel{P}{\to} X$, is the series bounded such that $X_n \leq X$ for all $n$?

Similar arguments are made in the first answer by Saz  at [Monotone increasing sequence of random variable that converge in probability implies convergence almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379309/monotone-increasing-sequence-of-random-variable-that-converge-in-probability-imp), but I cannot convince myself that monotonic and convergent series bounded by the limit. I know that there's a theorem stating that bounded and monotonic would lead to convergence but there's no theorem claiming that monotonic and convergence would lead to bounded.

Or how to show that:
$$\left\{\omega: |X_k(\omega)-X(\omega)|>\epsilon\right\} \subset \left\{\omega: |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|>\epsilon\right\},$$ for all $k\geq n$.

Comment: By monotonicity, you have pointwise convergence to a function $Y$, which may attain $+\infty$ as a value. Can you show that pointwise convergence to $Y$ and convergence in probability to $X$ imply that $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$ almost everywhere?

Comment: Intuitively, it is bounded. But how to show it is bounded at $X$? I just cannot find a theorem to rely on.

Comment: You don't generally have $X_n \leqslant X$ everywhere, only almost everywhere.

Comment: Please refer to my new edit for a mathematical statement.

Comment: That need only hold modulo null sets.