# prove that almost surely implies convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Prove that:

> if convergence almost surly(that is $P(\lim_nX_n = X) = 1$) to a
>   finite limit implies convergence in measure(that is
>   $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) \to 0$).

My attempt:

For convergence almost surely we can find a set $E$ with it's complement measure zero.On set $E$ we have $X_n \to X$ pointwise.

Hence by Egroff theorem we can find a subset of $U\subset E$ that $X_n$ convergence uniformly on $U$(with $E-U$ measure be arbitrary small $\eta$).

Hence For for any $\epsilon$ chosen by $|X_n-X|>\epsilon$.We have for any $\eta>0$ a $N(\epsilon) $ such that when $n>N$ ,we have$|X_n-X|>\epsilon$ can not happen on U.with it's complement measure arbitary small.

hence we have $P(\{|X_n-X|>\epsilon\})<P(X-E)+P(E-U) = \eta) $ which is arbitray small.hence convergence in measure

Is my proof correct?

A relavant converse case see here :[converse case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234567/non-decreasing-sequence-of-random-variable-convergence-in-probability-implies-it)

Comment: There is a standard proof which does not use Egoroff's Theorem and I am not sure if this proof would be considered as  a reasonable one.

Comment: Can you provide a reference about the standard proof,since I don't have it at my hand.

Comment: Every book on measure theoretic Probability Theory has  a proof. Examples: books of Chung, Breiman etc.

Comment: Maybe it's correct since convergence almost uniformly implies convergence in measure